# Python - index of list

Tags: python, indexing

Can anyone explain why this is not working and how to correct it? This is an example in "30 day Python" on Udemy. I've tried a lot, but I'm only getting errors.
Thx.

`list_d = ["Flower", "Pot", 123, "Daisy", 2328924]
list_e = []
for item in list_d:
if isinstance(item, int):
list_e.append(item)
list_d.pop(x)
x+=1`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: Don't change lists while iterating over them.

Comment: NihalSangeeth - sorry, next time I will write.
KlausD. - script should copy integers from one list to other, and remove from original list.

Comment: @ZofiaGarncarek please edit your question and post your code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be editing your list as you iterate over them. Apart from that, your usage of the variable x is quite confusing and is not correct.

Please see the below code:

```
list_d = ["Flower", "Pot", 123, "Daisy", 2328924]

list_e = []

for item in list_d:
    if isinstance(item,int):
        list_e.append(item)

for item in list_e:
    list_d.remove(item)

print list_e
print list_d
```

**Output:**

```
[123, 2328924]
['Flower', 'Pot', 'Daisy']
```

**Note:** This is just an edit of your answer to correct only the error in your code. There are more than one ways of doing this, you should be exploring it.

Comment: Thx. But is there any possibility to make it in one loop?

Comment: And "hi" to all!

Comment: You can't edit a list as you loop through it. You can probably use list comprehension to create the list of int. But, that involves looping through the list.

Comment: Ok. I undestand. Thx for all reply :)